# Wireless Problem Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless

My computer is a MacBook 2009 running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I'm using this system and the same wireless connection since October, but since yesterday my laptop cannot connect to my house WiFi any more. Somehow it does connect to my school's, and my friend's laptop does connect to my WiFi.

I already looked for some answers here, but none have helped me so far. [Following these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos), I [posted my log file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10295619/). I'm currently using my phone's hotspot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is your home network:

```
[  265.554197] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'WLAN-SSEWTM' [AC3]> (try 1/3) 
[  265.556317] wlan0: <MAC 'WLAN-SSEWTM' [AC3]> denied authentication (status 1) 
[  265.789379] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'WLAN-SSEWTM' [AC10]> 
[  265.809225] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'WLAN-SSEWTM' [AC10]> (try 1/3) 
[  265.991527] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'WLAN-SSEWTM' [AC10]> (try 2/3) 
[  265.994371] wlan0: <MAC 'WLAN-SSEWTM' [AC10]> denied authentication (status 1)
```

'Denied authentication' suggests that the wrong password was entered or, more likely, is stored in Network Manager. I suggest you click the network Manager icon, select 'Edit Connections,' highlight your home connection and delete it. Then, as a precaution, from the terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WLAN-SSEWTM
```

It is probably already gone; if so, just continue. Using another computer on the home network, log in to the administrative pages of the router and double-check the password.

Now, restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

NM should see your home network. Supply the password and connect.